# 500 Internal Server Error When Push Json To Firebase With Flask

Tags: python, firebase, flask

I get 500 internal server error when push json data from postman to firebase with flask, can anybody help me?

the json data i have posted like this `{"suhu": "20.3","lembab": "50%"}`

here my flask code

```py
@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return 'Welcome'

@app.route('/data', methods = ['POST'])
def esp():
    content = request.json
    nilai = jsonify(content)
    db.child("Monitoring").push(nilai)
    return nilai
```

when i comment `db.child("Monitoring").push(nilai)`
and `return nilai` the output is `{"lembab": "50%","suhu": "20.3"}`

It says 500 internal server error when i push the json data to firebase

Comment: Include the stack trace for the error